# shell script that send email before exiting

Tags: shell, amazon-ec2

i am trying to write a shell script that will send me an email before exiting itself

or

as i am running this on an amazon ec2 DEBAIN spot request and it should send me an email before the instances is terminated

```
            #!/bin/bash
            sendEmailLog()
            {
            emailLog=true
               if [ $emailLog = "true" ];then
                    /usr/bin/mpack -s "emailed log" -a "/srv/log.html" "emailid@gmail.com";
               fi
               exit 0;
            }

            trap sendEmailLog INT TERM EXIT KILL QUIT

            aws ec2 terminate-instances instances ID
```

i tried the above code it doesnot send me an email before its terminated
i am using DEBAIN 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might have a couple issues.  I'm not super-familiar with mpack, but it looks like your syntax is correct (except the ";" at the end).  Make a couple changes, below, and see if it helps.

I would use quotes define your emailLog string, although it's not really clear why you're using a string for a boolean statement that, as far as I can tell, you want to ALWAYS run.  Unless you want to get an error code.

```
 emailLog="true"
```

To check for equality, use two ==:

```
if [ $emailLog == "true" ]; then
```

And as I said, the ';' is superfluous.

If I were to re-write it, I would write it like this:

```
sendEmailLog() {
    /usr/bin/mpack -s "emailed log" -a "/srv/log.html" "emailid@gmail.com" && exit 1
    exit 0
}

trap sendEmailLog SIGINT SIGTERM SIGKILL

aws ec2 terminate-instances instances ID
```

Comment: Are you sure your `mpack` command works?  Have you tried it from the command line?  Looking closer at it, it doesn't appear that the `-a` is a supported switch.

Comment: yes i am sure it works with -a
in command line its working perfect

Comment: this is what i get after man mpack 

-a     Set the Content-Disposition to attachment.  If -a is not used the Content-Disposition is inline.

Comment: And that command successfully sends an email to the address desired from the amazon instance. Correct?

Comment: yes it send me an email successful in command line but its dosnt work when i terminate the system ..mpack works perfect for me .. and using SIGINT gives me an error (trap: SIGINT: bad trap) and using INT gives me no such error .. and i tested the same code with an infinite loop and then press Cltr^C then i successfully sends me an email but  on terminate i wont work

Comment: i guess while terminating the instances amazon ec2 send some other signal to end a running shell script and my script is not handling that signal in trap

Comment: Not sure why INT would work (at all) and SIGINT wouldn't. There might be a connection with this thread... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24950251/why-sigint-can-stop-bash-in-terminal-but-not-via-kill-int